# search excel column cell value

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim cmdString As String
Dim apptype As String

cmdString = InputBox("Enter Application type")

For Each Cl In ActiveSheet.Range("F3:Q54")
  If Cl.Value = cmdString Then
    Exit For
  End If
Next Cl
```

The code is getting that column values, but I want to get another column cell value of same row. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can access cells relative to the current cell using the [`Offset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property:

```
...
If Cl.Value = cmdString Then
  otherValue = Cl.Offset(0, num).Value
  Exit For
End If
...
```

where `num` is the offset of the column where the other cell is located (a negative number for columns left of the current cell, a positive number for columns right of the current cell).